# How do I get the ID from a selected row in a datagridview?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have a c# program build in Visual Studio 2015 with a datagridview connected to a MySQL database. Everything is working fine. But, when I click on a row it gets selected, now I want to get the ID that row has in my MySQL database to perform another query with it. How do I do this?

Comment: You can use a hidden column in datagridview to store the ID from the database...

Comment: It depends. Do you have that ID available in the data in that row? Or do you have that ID elsewhere within your view or backend classes (e.g. the viewmodel)?

Comment: I have a column named ID and it shows the auto_increment ID values that the database assigned to the records, and I have a column with a name. I want to query that ID when I click in the ID/Name on the datagridview to get the rest of the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should rather fetch the corresponding database key value(s) of the current row than the ID in the grid.

I had a similar problem some time ago. The solution was simply adding the key columns to the data source of the grid and - if required - hide them from view. Afterwards you can use these key values to perform all other kinds of actions (in my case: fetch child information from another table).

Using the ID from within your grid will be of no use.